VBAHow can i make a change of sheet, depending of what value i have on a cell, to move to the tab locati The values text are the same as the tab names
I have a list of Text Data that are the same as my tab names. I want to make a macro, that if i change the value of the cell, could move to the same tab name as the value cell name
i tried a code with ActiveSheet.Next.Select
im specting your help with ActiveSheet.Next.Select, to move into sheets depending of the value of my list

You need to solve 2 things:
The first is how to activate a sheet that has the name like the content of a cell. Now that's not hard. Considering that the cell is B2, the code would look like this:
Sub MoveToSheet()
    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
    On Error Resume Next   ' Prevent nasty errors when sheet doesn't exist
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
    If LCase(ActiveSheet.Name) <> LCase(sheetName) Then
        MsgBox "A sheet with name " & sheetName & " does not exist."
    End If
End Sub

Now what you want is that this routine is called automatically whenever the cell B2 is changed. For this, you need an event routine. The event is that something on the Worksheet is changed. To enable Excel to find this routine, it needs to have an exact name, in this case it's Worksheet_Change, it needs to have the correct parameters (in this case it's ByVal Target As Range), and it needs to be stored at the right place (the Worksheet module for the sheet where your cell is placed). If not all of these three conditions are met, Excel will not find it and nothing will happen.
If everything is okay, Excel will call this event routine whenever something is changed on the sheet. The parameter target will tell which cell(s) was modified. So we want to change the sheet only when the value of cell B2 was changed:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        MoveToSheet
    End If
End Sub

The strange looking construct Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing checks if the modified cells (Target) and your cell containing the sheet name (Range("B2")) have something in common. If not (eg cell B3 was changed), nothing will happen.

Now if I where you, I would slightly modify the code. The routine MoveToSheet shouldn't read the name of the sheet from cell B2, but expect it as parameter. The Event routine can pass it as argument:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        MoveToSheet Range("B2").Value
    End If
End Sub

Sub MoveToSheet(sheetName As String)
    On Error Resume Next   ' Prevent nasty errors when sheet doesn't exist
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
    If LCase(ActiveSheet.Name) <> LCase(sheetName) Then
        MsgBox "A sheet with name " & sheetName & " does not exist."
    End If
End Sub


thank you very much for the answer, the macro works perfectly and the explanations are amazing.

Try something like this
Dim TargetSheetName As String
TargetSheetName = "Sheet2"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheetName).Select

How you obtain the value "Sheet2" is a different story.
